# Draw a function by only using two input NOR gates

Tags: logic

T = (BD + A'BC'+A'CD)

How can i draw this by only using NOR-Gates? This is what i have done so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIujl.jpg

Have I understood this right?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Also, note that this kind of implement-it-with-gates digital electronics question is usually held to be off-topic, here.

Comment: @Ole I can recommend model checking as a technique to verify your design. You can use a tool like nuXmv to verify your design.

Comment: Thank you for the answers :) My question is basically just if I have understood it right. That's why i'm asking someone to check this. Might try to use some design analyzer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like you understood the question correctly and are implementing only using NOR-gates.

I also see correct usage of DeMorgan's Theorem.

Your answer seems to be **correct**. Good luck!

Comment: I assume you looked over the drawing :) ? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, checked the drawing too!